# Is it possible to set Class name in Preference as String and Retrieve it back and Fire that in Intent?

Tags: android

Is it possible to set a class name into Preference as String and Retrieve it back and set it in below line?

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SetClassName.class);
```

If yes, how can I do. This is to declare class name dynamically and fire back in Intent whenever needed

Comment: You use reflection after you store the full class path.

Comment: @JustinMitchell : Any Example?

Comment: I think that question is not as bad as it getting downvoted.

Comment: Yeah...Downvote karne walo "Janta Maaf Nahi Karegi"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the class name or full path in Shared Preference and and get it as a String then check the following code :

```
String myClass = "com.package.Activity";
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(myClass);
Activity obj = (Activity) myClass.newInstance();
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myClass);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ovi - That really helped